# During remote Actor creation, are Actors serialized?

Tags: akka

Let's say I have 2 remote nodes, A & B, which are both visible to each other over TCP and both running ActorSystems.

Node A has a jar containing Actor Foo in its classpath.  Node B does not.

If the ActorSystem on node A tells node B to remotely create a Foo Actor in its ActorSystem, will that work?  Will Foo's bytecode be sent to B over the wire or will it be necessary/expected that node B needs to have Foo in it's classpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't work. When the actor system on node A tells the actor system on node B to create a `Foo` actor, node A doesn't create the actor and send it across the wire. Rather, node A sends the `Props` for `Foo` (i.e., the recipe for creating a `Foo` actor) to node B and has node B create an instance of `Foo` (the `Props` for `Foo` must be serializable). Moreover, the classloader of the actor system for node B has to have a jar with the `Foo` class. From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/remoting.html#creating-actors-remotely):

> Creating Actors Remotely
>
> If you want to use the creation functionality in Akka remoting you have to further amend the `application.conf` file in the following way (only showing deployment section):

```
akka {
  actor {
    deployment {
      /sampleActor {
        remote = "akka.tcp://sampleActorSystem@127.0.0.1:2553"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> The configuration above instructs Akka to react when an actor with path `/sampleActor` is created, i.e. using `system.actorOf(Props(...), "sampleActor")`. This specific actor will not be directly instantiated, but instead the remote daemon of the remote system will be asked to create the actor, which in this sample corresponds to `sampleActorSystem@127.0.0.1:2553`.
>
> Once you have configured the properties above you would do the following in code:

```
val actor = system.actorOf(Props[SampleActor], "sampleActor")
actor ! "Pretty slick"
```

> **The actor class SampleActor has to be available to the runtimes using it, i.e. the classloader of the actor systems has to have a JAR containing the class.**

And farther down in the same section:

> Please note that remote deployment is not remote code loading, the Actors class to be deployed onto a remote system needs to be present on that remote system.